# Can htaccess redirect to cached files with newer modification dates?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, caching

My site (actively developed, single server) uses Apache htaccess to redirect to PHP scripts which generate cached versions of the requested files and then serve the cached versions using readfile(). The cached versions have little additions like meta tags that I need.

The first thing the caching script does is check if the cached file exists and is not older than either the original file or the caching script and if so, just serves it with header() and readfile(). This is reasonably fast of course, and it works easily since FTP sets mtime at upload.

However is there a way to get vanilla htaccess to do just the cache logic for me? Can htaccess redirects "branch" based on what is sort of a series of if/thens?

```
"FileName" -> ("Cached_FileName" does not exist) -> "CachingScript"
"FileName" -> ("Cached_FileName" is older than "FileName") -> "CachingScript"
"FileName" -> ("Cached_FileName" is older than "CachingScript") -> "CachingScript"
"FileName" -> "Cached_FileName"
```

It's not that I am experiencing any problems with my setup now -- just that I was wondering if htaccess could do this useful task itself, saving a PHP invocation for most hits, but keeping the ease of using mtime for active development.

Comment: I am not aware of any efficient way to compare the relation of time stamps on the level of request handling. The solutions I know all require some additional module to be loaded and used, which is not a real alternative here, since you then can simply use php instead, which does exactly that job.

Comment: What you can easily implement is the check whether a file exists. And often file names are used that contain a timetamp. But you can only directly compare such timestamps with a given one (a date for example). You cannot somehow easily check whether it is lower or bigger than the other one.